# Path from a point to a directed line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, algorithms

There is a man and a train on the points with positive integer coordinates. Both of man and train can only move horizontally, vertically or diagonally one unit per one hour. Movement of man/train is integer-discrete, not continuous.

The man want to take the train as soon as he can. He is running as he is really eager to catch the train, so speed of the man and the train is equal, for now. Direction of the train is fixed.

Given that two initial points $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$ of man and train respectively, and the direction of railroad - one of N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW - determine whether the man can catch the train.
If he can, compute the fastest time he can catch the train.

Example 1)
Man : $(2,5)$ / Train $(6,2)$ with direction NW:

Man can catch the train at $t=2$, $(4,4)$. (go east one step, go southeast one step)

Example 2)
Man : $(1,1)$ / Train $(1,2)$ with direction E:

Man can catch the train at $t=1$, $(2,2)$ (go northeast one step)

Example 3)
Man : $(1,1)$ / Train $(5,1)$ with direction N:

Man can catch the train at $t=4$, $(5,5)$ (go northeast four steps)

Example 4)
Man : $(1,1)$ / Train $(2,1)$ with direction E:

Man cannot catch the train.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: @Aretino Look at here:  "In general, determine whether the man can catch the train. If he can, compute the fastest time he can catch the train."